# 'Variable' is the part of Memory or name of the part of Memory?

Tags: variables, identifier

I'm looking for a clear and exact explanation of what a variable is. I've read some definitions of 'variable' but that made me confused .

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu9LG.jpg)

Let's suppose that we have a partition in our memory that we store a value (for example in this case an integer number like 5) and of course this partition has a name like my_age.

Now my Question is which one is the variable? The Partition that holds and stores a value is variable(2) or name of that partition(1) is the variable ?

Comment: The name for it. Variables are a concept of programming languages, not of machines.

Comment: It is the combination of *both*, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)) a variable is *a storage location paired with an associated symbolic name (an identifier)*. In that sense, languages like Python don't have variables, only names.

Comment: I think wikipedia is trying to say variable is that partition and it's name is identifier :( . do u agree ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: No. A variable is the combination of those things. Not either of them alone, at least according to that definition. Speaking loosely, for example in Python we only have identifiers, not variables, although people will often say "variable". But then, they are sometimes told by Pythonistas that "python has names, not variables".

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: this sentence was in Deitel & Deitel book : "A variable is a location in the computer’s memory where a value can be stored for use later in a program. All Java variables must be declared with a name and a type before they can be used. A variable’s name enables the program to access the value of the variable in memory" .